# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 in ionic 3

Tags: json, ionic3, ionic4

I am working on ionic 3 app. when i run it on browser its working fine but when i run as a apk or on mobile it gives me error ‘Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1’ as shown in screenshot https://prnt.sc/q0jxlf . i dont know why its occuring in apk while its working accurately on browser siple ionic serve run.this is my code

```
register(user)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => {debugger;

        this.http.post(global.apiUrl + "register", user.value)


            // .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {debugger;
                this.data = data;
                resolve(this.data);
            },error =>{debugger;
                let jsonE = JSON.parse(error._body);

                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        subTitle:jsonE.error,
                        buttons: ['OK']
                    });
                    alert.present();

                }
            );
    });
```

please help me i am musch confused

Comment: try without JSON.parse, e.g. let jsonE = error._body;

Comment: i tried without JSON.Parse https://prnt.sc/q0koox is output . this https://prnt.sc/q0kp40 one is response from server. problem is that while i run on browser its work properly it get value from server accuratelt but when i run like apk it give me response which i attached above. how could this be resolvable

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had a similar issue to this and it seems what I did solved the issue. The angular Http Client returns an error object that includes and error and message property. I used those to display to the user for errors, but in cases of submission timeouts or disconnections during the submissions my backend would spit out a different error not caught by the Http client.

```js
error =>{debugger;
    let jsonE = 'Uncaught Error!';
    if(error._body != undefined){
      let err = JSON.parse(error._body);
      jsonE = err.error
    }
    
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Error!',
       subTitle: jsonE,
       buttons: ['OK']
     });
    alert.present();

    }
```

I would probably go as far as adding a try, catch block inside wrapped around your error handling because it seems that the error body is inconsistent.

Comment: thanks alot for your precious response. unfortunatelly facing same error as you can see in screenshot https://prnt.sc/q2q2nv

Comment: Try removing your JSON.parse statement all together and put a string in the error subTitle